# include linux kernel headers for btrfs filesystem

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, linux-device-driver, btrfs

In my linux kernel driver, I need to cast struct inode to struct btrfs_inode.
in order to do it, i looked at implementation of [btrfs_getattr](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/btrfs/inode.c?v=2.6.30#L4741).

the code is pretty simple:

```
#include "/data/kernel/linux-4.1.21-x86_64/fs/btrfs/ctree.h"
#include "/data/kernel/linux-4.1.21-x86_64/fs/btrfs/btrfs_inode.h"
static dev_t get_device_id_btrfs(struct inode* inode){
if (inode != NULL) {
    struct btrfs_inode *btrfsInode;
    btrfsInode = BTRFS_I(inode);
    if (btrfsInode != NULL && btrfsInode->root != NULL) {
        return btrfsInode->root->anon_dev;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

in order to compile i must add the headers on top of the function:

```
#include "/data/kernel/linux-4.1.21-x86_64/fs/btrfs/ctree.h"
#include "/data/kernel/linux-4.1.21-x86_64/fs/btrfs/btrfs_inode.h"
```

**What is the problem ?**
I must manually download and include ctree.h and btrfs_inode.h, they are not provided in the kernel-headers package.
On every platform I compile my driver, I have specific VM for the distro/kernel version, so on every VM I usually download package kernel-headers and everything compiles perfectly.

btrfs was introduced in kernel 3.0 above.
Arent the btrfs headers should be there ? 
do they exist in another package ? maybe fs-headers or something like that ?

Thanks

Comment: Headers under `fs/btrfs` contains API **private for btrfs driver**: this API is intended to be used *only in the driver's implementation*. So, whole your purpose - `I need to cast struct inode to struct btrfs_inode` - isn't "good", because your are trying to **use other's private API**. In such cases there is no common approaches for get such API.

Comment: suse solved this by calling  (inode->i_op->getattr(NULL, dentry, &kstat), I wanted to avoid the overhead and simply do the cast.. so i looked in btrfs inode getattr implementation.

Comment: How does your code know that the inode belongs to a btrfs file system?

Comment: by checking the inode's superblock type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by download kernel-sources package and then modified makefile.
This solution may not be recommended, but it is acceptable by me since I build kernel driver that fits only certain kernels/distros which I maintain.
include the following headers:

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3,0,0)
#include <fs/btrfs/ctree.h>
#include <fs/btrfs/btrfs_inode.h>
#endif
```

and to the Makefile i modified the EXTRA_CFLAGS property *"-I/lib/modules/$(KERNEL_HEADERS)/source"* :

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS    +=-D__Linux -std=gnu99 -I/lib/modules/$(KERNEL_HEADERS)/source
```